# aerender from C# console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, render, after-effects

I'm trying to render an Adobe After Effects composition from a C# Console Application but it's not working. It doesn't even give any error, the code executes smoothly.

`string strCmdText = @"""C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2022\\Support Files\\aerender -project C:\\ForRadio\\AE_Comp\\InputScenes.aep""";`

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);`

```
 Process cmd = new Process();
        string strCmdText = @"""C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2022\\Support Files\\aerender -project C:\\ForRadio\\AE_Comp\\InputScenes.aep""";
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
        cmd.Start();
```

I have tried both the variations of code and it's not throwing any error. When I run this command in the command prompt it works, but not when I execute from within my C# console app.
`C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2022\\Support Files\\aerender -project C:\\ForRadio\\AE_Comp\\InputScenes.aep`

Comment: Maybe your console application ends before the process has been finished?

Comment: I don't think you want to create your strings with both @ and double \ and " characters. Debug or use Console.WriteLine to check your strCmdText variable.

Comment: I think you need FileName = {path}\aerender (or maybe even aerender.exe), and Arguments = "-project ..."